# Configuration of iptables (verfication, actives services, allow FTP)

Tags: configuration, ftp, iptables

I’m experimenting with IPT's (iptables) in Xubuntu.

First experimentation wato allow all OUTPUT traffic and block all INPUT except already existing TCP connections can somebody verify if these are correct

[image]

To go a bit more advanced I'm trying to allow als TCP connections to active services on my workstation. My idea is to do a nmap scan and grep the listening/open ports but I'm probably over thinking it.

Finally I'm trying to allow FTP.
I used this additional rule to allow FTP but it seems I still get blocked

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: i do know that images can only be posted at 10 rep but i think it is more clear what i want achieved with a img

Comment: It's better just copy and pste the text from terminal to your question.

Comment: Can you try `sudo iptables -A -p tcp --dport 21 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT`. FTP opens another connection for data transfer. I think "RELATED" should handle that.

Comment: still getting blocked. I must add that i'm trying to connect to a xubuntu that runs in VMPlayer from Windows with WinSCP but that shouldn't realy be a problem. Also tried to ftp to localhost in ubuntu -> connection refused :S

Comment: Try to load the FTP connection tracking module `sudo modprobe nf_conntrack_ftp`. You can also try `sudo iptables -A -p tcp --dport 21 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED`.

Comment: still getting refused - screen of uptodate ipt can be found here --> http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=1eb1c3d

Comment: OK, looking at the screenshot I realise now that iptables is blocking nothing, the policy for all chains is ACCEPT, which means if no rule is matched the packet is accepted. The refused message usualy means the port is closed. I don't think you have an FTP server running (`sudo netstat -tlnp` to check, search for port 21).

Comment: @EricCarvalho - good point. All the rules should be listed to debug an iptables problem.

Comment: thnx for the response ... will experiment further tomorrow. Kinda strange that the the default behaviour is accept - in windows server if i remember it well it's deny

Comment: setup a vsftpd server - however when i try to login i get this error - 500 OOPS: cannot read user list file:/etc/vsftpd.userlist - edit: typo in the config file got a working ftp server now to my home folder ;) -  only the question left on how to allow all  allow als TCP connections to active services on my workstation

Comment: @EricCallho so basically what you are saying that you always need a deny all or iptables will assume it is allowed?

Comment: Yes, to change the policy (default behavior if no rule matches) run, e.g., `sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP`, `sudo iptables -P OUTPUT DROP`, etc.

Comment: interesting fact

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FTP is a bit odd in that to allow inbound traffic on port 21 and outbound traffic on port 20 :

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 20 -j ACCEPT
```

In addition ftp will use a random higher port. To allow this you need to load the ip_conntrack_ftp module on boot. Uncomment and modify the IPTABLES_MODULES line in the /etc/sysconfig/iptables-config file to read

```
IPTABLES_MODULES="ip_conntrack_ftp"
```

You will still need a way to save your iptables configuration and restore it when you boot. Ubuntu does not have a simple way of doing this. Basically you can either use `/etc/rc.local` or disable NetworkManager and use networking scripts.

First save your rules:

```
sudo iptables-save /etc/iptables.save
```

Method 1 : Edit `/etc/rc.local` and add the line

```
iptables-restore /etc/iptables.save
```

Method 2 : Edit `/etc/network/interfaces` and use "post-up" to bring our iptables rules up.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
post-up /sbin/iptables-restore /etc/iptables.save
```

Then reboot.

The preferred method is probably to use UFW

```
sudo ufw allow ftp
```

UFW is the fedault tool for Ubuntu, uses syntax very similar to iptables, and is enabled and restored on rebooting.

See:

https://serverfault.com/questions/38398/allowing-ftp-with-iptables

http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html

http://bodhizazen.com/Tutorials/iptables

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to iptables, you may want to use either [gufw](http://gufw.org/) or [ufw](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW) to set up rules initially.  You can use rules as simple as "allow incoming ftp" instead of needing to understand all of the special flags to make it work.  They will also allow you to set up advanced rules if you need to.

Both ufw and gufw create iptables rules behind the scenes.

Comment: thnx for lettting my know those tool exists but i want to train my console kunfu

Comment: you can still use them to set up a sample rule, then use console iptables to see what they spit out.