# Where is /etc/sysconfig/iptables-config in 14.04

Tags: iptables

Where is /etc/sysconfig/iptables-config in 14.04

I can't comment in this thread because I do not have a reputation of 50
[Configuration of iptables (verfication, actives services, allow FTP)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/261626/configuration-of-iptables-verfication-actives-services-allow-ftp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured this out on my own. To allow FTP on Ubuntu 14.04, in addition to allowing the port in iptables you need to...

```
sudo nano /etc/modules
```

and add the following to the end of the file

```
ip_conntrack_ftp
```